# How to get rid of Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, typescript

I have a function that queries a database and then returns a `string[]` like this:

```
{
        "result":[
            {
                "courses_dept":"adhe",
                "courses_id":"327",
                "courses_avg":100,
                "courses_instructor":"walker, judith",
                "courses_title":"teach adult",
                "courses_pass":21,
                "courses_fail":0,
                "courses_audit":0
            }
        ]

}
```

Then I want another function that filters the `string[]` based on keywords.

```
public getResultArray(query: QueryRequest, resultArray: string[]): QueryResponse {

    let tempRes: string[] = [];

    for (let index:any in resultArray) {
        // code to filter the array...
       tempRes.push(resultArray[index]);
    }

    let result: QueryResponse = tempRes;

    return { result };

}
```

The output for `getResultArray` is this:

```
{
    "result":{
        "result":[
            {
                "courses_dept":"adhe",
                "courses_id":"327",
                "courses_pass":21,
                "courses_fail":0,
                "courses_audit":0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I output the result for `getResultArray` so that it only prints the key name `result` ONCE? I don't want one result object nested in another. I know it's happening because I created two objects called `result` but I don't know how to do what I want to do without creating the extra objects.

Comment: try - `return result.result`

Comment: @AbbasKararawala `result.result` doesn't seem to be an option in typescript.

Comment: Why not `return result`? (Without the surrounding object)

Comment: Change `return { result };` to `return result;`

Comment: @evolutionxbox haha that was it. thanks.